# ¿Alguna forma de insertar registros cuando la tabla tiene default e identity en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, insert, constraints

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_ADD_CLIENTE
@PNIDTIPDOCUMENTO INT,
@PSNUMDOCUMENTO VARCHAR(35),
@PSNOMBRES VARCHAR(40),
@PSAPEPAT VARCHAR(25),
@PSAPEMAT VARCHAR(25),
@PSCORREO VARCHAR(40),
@PSTELEF VARCHAR(25),
@PNESTADO INT,
@PSUSUREG VARCHAR(40)
AS
    INSERT CLIENTE VALUES (NULL,@PNIDTIPDOCUMENTO,@PSNUMDOCUMENTO,@PSNOMBRES,@PSAPEPAT,@PSAPEMAT,@PSCORREO,@PSTELEF,@PNESTADO,@PSUSUREG)
GO


EXEC USP_ADD_CLIENTE 1,'21245312','JUAN','CASTRO','ASDASDAS','JCARLOS@OUTLOOK.COM','124124',1,'CPEREZ'
```

Mi tabla tiene el PK Identity y la fecha de registro seteada con el día de hoy por DEFAULT, sim embargo me sale el siguiente error cuando ejecuto mi SP.

**Mens 8101, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento USP_ADD_CLIENTE, Línea 21
Sólo puede especificarse un valor explícito para la columna de identidad de la tabla 'CLIENTE' cuando se usa una lista de columnas e IDENTITY_INSERT es ON.**

PD: Incluso he tratado de definir mis SP especificando la fecha como default

`INSERT CLIENTE VALUES (NULL,@PNIDTIPDOCUMENTO,@PSNUMDOCUMENTO,@PSNOMBRES,@PSAPEPAT,@PSAPEMAT,@PSCORREO,@PSTELEF,@PNESTADO,DEFAULT,@PSUSUREG)` y me dice que no pueden haber dos null con identidad. Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: simplemente quita el `NULL` que estás poniendo

Comment: ... y tienes que ser explícito en la lista de columnas al que le asignas valor en tu `INSERT`. `INSERT CLIENTE (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)`

Comment: Lamak : no me salió así, no deja crear el SP

Comment: tomaste en cuenta el comentario de @sstan?

Comment: sstan : Y debo incluir tanto la columna del identity como la columna del default? o los obvio?

Comment: Lamak (2) : Sí pero por separado del tuyo,juntaré ambos y les aviso

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos,me salió tal y como esperaba.

Answer (score 2):

Para que no quede abierta la pregunta sin respuesta...

En tu insert, no debes asignarle valor a la columna `IDENTITY`. En tu caso, debes quitar el `NULL` al principio. Pero esto solo lo puedes lograr si usas la notación `INSERT` donde enumeras las columnas explícitamente, que es la mejor práctica de todas maneras.

```
INSERT CLIENTE (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres insertar registros en una tabla así:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [nombreTabla] ON
INSERT...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [nombreTabla] OFF
```